# Proof verification of Atiyah-Macdonald, Exercise 2.26

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Exercise 2.26: Let $N$ be an $A$-module. Then $N$ is flat if and only if $\operatorname{Tor}_1(A/\mathfrak{a},N) = 0$ for all finitely generated ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ in $A$.

I think the proof is mainly correct; but I am not sure about the last part where I pass the ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ of $A$ to the direct limits of their finitely generated submodules. I'm not sure if $\varinjlim (A/\mathfrak{a}_i) = A/\mathfrak{a}$. Here is my proof:

> The forward direction is trivial. Now $N$ is flat if $\operatorname{Tor}_1(M,N) = 0$ for all finitely generated $A$-modules $M$; here is the reason. Any $A$-module $M$ is the direct limit of its finitely generated submodules, say $M = \varinjlim M_i$. Consider a SES of $A$-modules $0 \to P \to Q \to N \to 0$, and tensor with some $M_i$. If $\operatorname{Tor}_1(M_i,N) = 0$ for all $i$, then the sequence $0 \to P\otimes M_i \to Q \otimes M_i \to N \otimes M_i \to 0$ would be exact for all $i$. Pass to the direct limit to obtain a SES $0 \to \varinjlim(P\otimes M_i) \to \varinjlim(Q \otimes M_i) \to \varinjlim(N \otimes M_i) \to 0$, where since direct limits commute with tensor products, we conclude that $\operatorname{Tor}_1(M,N) = 0$ indeed. Thus, it is enough to show that $\operatorname{Tor}_1(M,N)=0$ for finitely generated $M$.

> Now suppose $M$ is finitely generated with generators $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Denote by $M_i = \left<x_1,\ldots,x_i\right>$, the submodule of $M$ generated by elements up to $i$. For each $i >1$, we have SESs $0 \to M_{i-1} \to M_i \to M_i/M_{i-1} \to 0$, where $M_i/M_{i-1}$ is generated by $x_i$, so is of the form $A/\mathfrak{a}$ for an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset A$ thought of as the relations on $x_i$. Now, if each $\left<x_i\right>$ is flat, then by Exercise 25 (for an SES $0\to N^\prime \to N \to N^{\prime\prime} \to 0$ with $N^{\prime\prime}$ flat, $N$ is flat iff $N^\prime$ is flat) this implies $M_2$ is flat (from the SES $0 \to M_1 \to M_2 \to M_2/M_1\to 0$) and $M_3$ flat from the next SES and so on up to implying $M_n = M$ is flat. Therefore, it is enough to show $\operatorname{Tor}_1(A/\mathfrak{a},N) = 0$ for all ideals $\mathfrak{a} \subset A$.

> Now as an $A$-module, ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ are again a direct limit of its finitely generated submodules $\mathfrak{a}_i$. Thus, by assumption we have $0 \to \mathfrak{a}_i \otimes N \to A \otimes N \to (A/\mathfrak{a}_i)\otimes N \to 0$ for every $i$. Passing through the direct limit, we get $0 \to \mathfrak{a} \otimes N \to A \otimes N \to (A/\mathfrak{a}) \otimes N \to 0$, which implies $\operatorname{Tor}_1(A/\mathfrak{a},N) = 0$ for all ideals $\mathfrak{a} \subset A$.

I would like any feedback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarkBennet Edited; totally forgot to include the problem itself. Thanks for pointing out.